# 2d array of objects, each with own arraylist, all appear to have the same arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make the classic coin change application that accepts different values of coins and creates change using the least amount of coins. It's supposed to use dynamic programming and a custom change class. My problem is that All of the `numberOfCoins`variables are correct, but it seems like all of the `Coins` ArrayLists are referencing the same ArrayList. I feel like it is something fundamental that I'm not getting because I've never used ArrayLists before, or something with where I am creating the objects, but I just can't put my finger on it. Not looking for a handout, just a little nudge in the right direction.

**My Class:**

```
public class Change {
public int numberOfCoins;
public List<Integer> Coins = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Change(int x){
    numberOfCoins = x;
}

Change(int x, ArrayList<Integer> c){
    numberOfCoins = x;
    Coins = c;
}

public void printChange(int j){
    System.out.println("The fewest number of coins to make $." + j + " is " + numberOfCoins);
    System.out.println("The coins used are:" + Coins.toString());
}
}
```

**My Program:**

```
    Change[][] C = new Change[valuesArrayLength + 1][j + 1];

    for(int y = valuesArrayLength - 1; y >= 0; y--){
        for(int x = 0; x <= j; x++){
            if(x == 0){
                C[y][x] = new Change(0);
            }
            else if(value[y] > x){
                C[y][x] = new Change(C[y+1][x].numberOfCoins, (ArrayList<Integer>) C[y+1][x].Coins);
            }
            else{
                if(y + 1 == valuesArrayLength){         // avoid referring to null and filling table with 0s (first time through j, when (i or y) = valuesArrayLength)
                    C[y][x] = new Change(1 + C[y][x - value[y]].numberOfCoins, (ArrayList<Integer>) C[y][x - value[y]].Coins);
                    C[y][x].Coins.add(value[y]);
                }
                else{
                    if(1 + C[y][x - value[y]].numberOfCoins < C[y+1][x].numberOfCoins){
                        C[y][x] = new Change(1 + C[y][x - value[y]].numberOfCoins, (ArrayList<Integer>) C[y][x - value[y]].Coins);
                        C[y][x].Coins.add(value[y]);
                    }    
                    else{
                        C[y][x] = new Change(C[y+1][x].numberOfCoins, (ArrayList<Integer>) C[y+1][x].Coins);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    C[i][j].printChange(j);

}
```

Comment: Can we see how exactly are you initializing the elements of the `Change[][] C`?

Comment: @R.J I think that's what is shown. Though as a side note this is an awfully complicated way to solve a problem that's extremely simple. What's confusing me is why there is a multidimensional array of lists at all. : / OP, what is `value[]` and what is in it?

Comment: @Radiodef - Everywhere it is just `new Change(C[y+1][x].numberOfCoins, (ArrayList<Integer>) C[y+1][x].Coins);`. Not 1 place has a new ArrayList has been passed, which means, either `null` was passed a parameter or the `Coins` was populated before which is being passed always, everywhere.

Comment: @R.J Yeah you're right. Presumably the only place a new ArrayList is shown to be instantiated and not reassigned is the `if (x == 0) { C[y][x] = new Change(0); }` part.

Comment: @Radiodef, value[] is the array of denomination values

Comment: @R.J that was my problem was that `Coins` was being passed everywhere. I was assuming that by creating new `Change` objects that it would create new `Coins` ArrayLists

Comment: @philthyfool - If that solves your problem, that's good! :) I just didn't have enough evidence to say it for sure, thus the comment.

Comment: It is. You guys saved me a lot of time and frustration on something that is pretty simple and I sincerely appreciate your help. But, just to be sure I'm understanding everything correctly, I was thinking that when I created a new `Change` object it would create a new ArrayList, but since I was using the constructor that takes the two arguments it wasn't instantiating a new ArrayList as I had defined outside the constructor, right?

Comment: It pretty much seems to be that case. You might have created an arraylist and passed its reference(as a value) around everywhere, thus all the `Coins` were referring to the same arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Change(int x, ArrayList<Integer> c){
    numberOfCoins = x;
    Coins = new ArrayList<Integer>(c);
}
```

Comment: If a new/different arraylist is sent to the constructor always, then this is just an overkill. Unless the OP posts the code where the `C` array is filled with values, this should just be a speculative answer.

Comment: I feel so dumb, but that took care of it. I had a feeling it was something like that. I thought by creating a new change object for each location in the 2d array, it wouldn't affect the ones previously created.